# Generate report for loans receipts (refunds or reverse transaction)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i'm working on system for NGO that's give a loans for poor people with out any interest ,and the Borrower repaid to the organization monthly payments
**my problem with reverse transactions or refunds when employee inserted payments with wrong value ,so he should make reverse for this transaction 
and i made it by insert the negative value for this payments**

i have **loans** **table** with following columns :

```
id ║   amount  ║ loan_date  ║ created_on  ║ emp_id      ║   client_id ║
═══╬═══════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
1  ║    10,000 ║ 2011-01-01 ║  2010-01-01 ║    100      ║    600      ║
```

**Receipts** **Table**

```
id ║  loan_id  ║ p_amount   ║ p_date      ║ rev_p_id    ║ created_on  ║
═══╬═══════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
1  ║    1      ║ 500        ║  2011-01-01 ║   null      ║  2011-01-01 ║
═══╬═══════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
2  ║    1      ║ 500        ║  2011-02-01 ║   null      ║  2011-01-01 ║
═══╬═══════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
3  ║    1      ║ 500        ║  2011-03-01 ║   null      ║  2011-01-01 ║
═══╬═══════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
4  ║    1      ║ -500       ║  2011-04-01 ║    2        ║  2011-01-01 
═══╬═══════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
5  ║    1      ║ 500        ║  2011-05-01 ║   null      ║  2011-01-01 ║
═══╬═══════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
6  ║    1      ║ 500        ║  2011-06-01 ║   null      ║  2011-01-01 ║
═══╬═══════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
7  ║    1      ║ 500        ║  2011-07-01 ║   null      ║  2011-01-01 ║
```

my problem when i want generate report i use sum query between date for example 
case 1 
between 2011-01-01 to 2011-06-01 should give me =2500 
and its true because the payment number 2 and the reverse for it in between the range of date

case 2 
between 2011-03-01 to 2011-06-01  should give me = 1500   and doesn't sum the negative receipts because the it's reverse to payment id 2 and it's not in this period

**how i can determine when i should sum the reverse value or not by mysql
and php i'm using codeigniter and mysql**

Answer (score 0):

I would do a self-join on your `receipts` table to get the date of the reversed transaction for any reversals and use this date to decide whether a reversal is in the period of the report:

```
select r1.loan_id, sum(r1.p_amount) sum_amount
from receipts r1
left join receipts r2 on r1.rev_p_id=r2.id
where coalesce(r2.p_date,r1.p_date)>=... and coalesce(r2.p_date,r1.p_date)<=...
group by r1.loan_id
```

`coalesce()` function is used to return the first non-null date. For a regular payment, `r2.p_date` would be null (it does not reverse anything), so the actual `p_date` will be used. For a reversal `r2.p_date` would be not null (it would have the reversed payment's date), therefore `coalesce()` would return this date.

Comment: Thank you so much i will try your solution now

Comment: you solution not working for me because i need to get all receipts and because we use group by

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not get your point. Pls elaborate. Also remember, that your question is **not** about getting all receipts, it is about getting a sum for a given period.